Masking ip with nginx
my server uses external services that are not available in my country, I want to use a proxy in order to hide my ip from other services, I tried many options, none helped, while I'm trying to configure nginx for this, they write about this setting everywhere:
`server{
listen 80;
server_name myIP;
location / {
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header Host $host;
proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5001;
proxy_http_version 1.1;
proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
}
}
server{
listen proxyPort;
server_name _;
proxy_set_header Authorization "Basic base64(login and password proxy)";
return 301 http://proxyIP;
}`

is it possible to hide your ip using nginx? if yes, what am I doing wrong, if not, what should I use.
p.s. I don't use anything except nginx. The port that needs to be masked is allocated for the websocket server. To use my proxy, you need to specify the ip, port, username and password
I tried to set up a global proxy on ubuntu, set up 3proxy, set up a proxy via nginx
